# How to push a gulp pipeline onto another

Tags: gulp

I would like to process a series of folders through the build pipeline. For each folder I start another gulp pipeline that will create some source files. Finally I'd like to pipe them all together through the zip() plugin to produce a final artifact. 
The following pseudocode shows my approach. However, I cannot push the result of the `gulp.src` to the current pipeline.

```
return gulp.src(someFolder)
           .pipe(through(function(folder, enc, cb){
               // how to add the result of the following line to my 
               // own pipeline????
               this.push(gulp.src(path.join(folder, "whatever"))
                             .pipe(somePlugin()));

            }))
            .pipe(zip(....))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(....));
```

Any hints how to combine those pipelines together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what [`gulp-foreach`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-foreach) is intended for. Using that the equivalent of the code you posted would look like this:

```
var foreach = require('gulp-foreach');

return gulp.src(someFolder)
  .pipe(foreach(function(stream, folder) {
     return gulp.src(path.join(folder.path, "whatever"))
       .pipe(somePlugin());
 }))
 .pipe(zip(....))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(....));
```

Note that the above will discard all files from the original `gulp.src(someFolder)`. They will not be included in the ZIP. If you want to keep those around as well you can use [`merge-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream):

```
var foreach = require('gulp-foreach');
var merge = require('merge-stream');

return gulp.src(someFolder)
  .pipe(foreach(function(stream, folder) {
     return merge(stream,
       gulp.src(path.join(folder.path, "whatever"))
         .pipe(somePlugin()));
 }))
 .pipe(zip(....))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(....));
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thanks, was not aware of this plugin.